# Typescript how to map type keys to camelCase

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript but I want to create a mapped type that converts keys from another type. Specifically, say I have a type where all the keys are snake-cased, how can I create a type where they are all camel-cased?

I thought I could do something like

```
type CamelCase<T> = {
  [_.camelCase(P in keyof T)]: T[P];
}

type MyCamelCaseType = CamelCase<SnakeCaseType>;
```

But TS doesn't like this. How can I transform the keys of an existing type to create a new type in this way?

Comment: Currently not possible in typescript

Comment: Related https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Typescript 4.1, template literal types got quite an upgrade. This is a problem I have wanting to be solved for a while and with a bit of tweaking managed to come up with this:

```
type CamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer P1}_${infer P2}${infer P3}`
  ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${Uppercase<P2>}${CamelCase<P3>}`
  : Lowercase<S>

type KeysToCamelCase<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as CamelCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends {} ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K]> : T[K]
}


interface SnakeCase {
    bar_value: string;
    baz_value: {
        blah_test: number;
    }
}

const transformed: KeysToCamelCase<SnakeCase> = {
    bazValue: {
        blahTest: 2
    },
    barValue: 'test'
}
```

I can recommend reading: https://dev.to/phenomnominal/i-need-to-learn-about-typescript-template-literal-types-51po and also trying some of these Typescript challenges https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges to learn more about these literal types.

Comment: How would this work for arrays? If the `SnakeCase` contains an `array`, the final generated type seems to throw the following error, after trying to use an array function on it. 

`TS2349: This expression is not callable.Type 'KeysToCamelCase<ArrayType>' has no call signatures.`

For example if this is the object you want to transform:
```
{
    bar_value: string;
    baz_value: [{
        blah_test: number;
    }]
}
```

Then the transformed `bazValue.map(() => {})` will throw an error. Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: I think, `Lowercase<S>` isn't nessessary, but its existence makes imposible to apply `CamelCase` to keys that are already in camel case

Comment: awosome! Is any possible to do this opposite? snakecase to camelcase?

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I tried to understand the code but there's one thing I couldn't figure out. Would you please let me know why we need to use  `CamelCase<string & K>`? What does the `& K` do in this part?

Comment: Actually, it's more like `K & string`. That's because `keyof T` type is not only a string type, but rather `string | number | symbol`. So we need to limit type of `K` only to string type, because `CamelCase` type expects only strings.

Comment: How do we type an indexer for `const test={} as KeysToCamelCase<T>`? When I try typing a variable like `const key:CamelCase<string & typeof T> = "cameledMember"` I get the error: `Type 'CamelCase<string & keyof T>' cannot be used to index type 'KeysToCamelCase<T>'`

Comment: I changed `blah_test` to `number[]` and it gives me this error `Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'KeysToCamelCase<number[]>': tostring, tolocalestring, indexof, lastindexof, and 7 more.ts(2740)
script.ts(5, 27): The expected type comes from property 'blahTest' which is declared here on type 'KeysToCamelCase<{ blah_test: number[]; }>'`, even though it's `[1]`

Comment: Is there a version of this for going in the other direction (ie. to underscores)?

Answer (score 8):

In case you have an object with nested arrays in it, you can wrap it a bit more.
Based on Max Eisenhardts answer.

We can check on an Array type, and if so, take the object type of that Array in the already existing functionality.

If we don't do this, array functions will be marked as not callable.

```
 type CamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer P1}_${infer P2}${infer P3}`
    ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${Uppercase<P2>}${CamelCase<P3>}`
    : Lowercase<S>

  type ObjectToCamel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as CamelCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends Record<string, any> ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K]> : T[K]
  }

  type KeysToCamelCase<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as CamelCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends Array<any> ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K][number]>[] : ObjectToCamel<T[K]>
  }
```

Comment: `KeysCamelArray` is not defined

Comment: Made a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: To save an array elements type, you should pass it `T[K] extends Record<string, any>`

Comment: The `ObjectToCamel` type is losing array prototype functions. To fix this, use @MikeKokadii 's answer, where you switch `Record<string, any>` to `Record<string, K>`

Answer (score 1):

And the reverse transformation in addition to Max Eisenhardt's answer for those who asked:

```
type UpperCaseLetters = (
  'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' |
  'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' |
  'Y' | 'Z' | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
)

type SnakeCaseSeq<S extends string> = S extends `${infer P1}${infer P2}`
  ? P1 extends UpperCaseLetters
    ? `_${Lowercase<P1>}${SnakeCaseSeq<P2>}`
    : `${P1}${SnakeCaseSeq<P2>}`
  : Lowercase<S>;

export type SnakeCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer P1}${infer P2}`
  ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${SnakeCaseSeq<P2>}`
  : Lowercase<S>;

type ObjectToSnakeCase<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as SnakeCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends Record<string, any>
    ? KeysToSnakeCase<T[K]>
    : T[K];
};

export type KeysToSnakeCase<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as SnakeCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends Array<any>
    ? KeysToSnakeCase<T[K][number]>[]
    : ObjectToSnakeCase<T[K]>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Max Eisenhardt and Hespen answers, I suggest the solution that will worked even if you have snake case keys in your original type already. Otherwise you will have next transformation: `camelCase` -> `camelcase`

```
type CamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer P1}_${infer P2}${infer P3}`
    ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${Uppercase<P2>}${CamelCase<P3>}`
    : Lowercase<S>

type ObjectToCamel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as CamelCase<string &K>]: T[K] extends Record<string, K> ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K]> : T[K]
}

type KeysToCamelCase<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer P1}_${infer P2}`
        ? CamelCase<string &K>
        : K
    ]: T[K] extends Array<K>
        ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K][number]>[]
        : ObjectToCamel<T[K]>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [Max Eisenhardt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65015868/13214670)

This will recursively handle as many snake/dashes/some delimiter that are present in an object's key. Accounts for unrolling array types to maintain array structures.

```
/** Converts a string to camel-case based on some delimiter */
export type CamelCaseFrom<S extends string, Delimiter extends string> = CamelCaseFromHelper<S, Delimiter>;

type CamelCaseFromHelper<S extends string, Delimiter extends string, NotFirstToken extends boolean = false> =
    NotFirstToken extends true
        ? S extends `${infer P1}${Delimiter}${infer P2}`
            ? `${Capitalize<P1>}${CamelCaseFromHelper<P2, Delimiter, true>}`
            : `${Capitalize<S>}`
        : S extends `${infer P1}${Delimiter}${infer P2}`
            ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${CamelCaseFromHelper<P2, Delimiter, true>}`
            : `${Lowercase<S>}`;

/** Convert an object's keys to camel-case based on some delimiter */
export type KeysToCamelCase<T, Delimiter extends string> = {
    [K in keyof T as CamelCaseFrom<string &K, Delimiter>]:
        T[K] extends Array<infer ArrayElement>
            ? KeysToCamelCaseForArrayElement<ArrayElement, Delimiter>
            : T[K] extends {}
                ? KeysToCamelCase<T[K], Delimiter>
                : T[K];
}

/** Handles selecting keys from nested arrays */
type KeysToCamelCaseForArrayElement<AElement, Delimiter extends string> =
    AElement extends Array<infer BElement>
        ? Array<KeysToCamelCaseForArrayElement<BElement, Delimiter>>
        : Array<KeysToCamelCase<AElement, Delimiter>>;

/* CONVENIENCE TYPINGS */
export type CamelCaseFromKebabCase<S extends string> = CamelCaseFrom<S, '-'>;
export type CamelCaseFromSnakeCase<S extends string> = CamelCaseFrom<S, '_'>;
```

**Example 1**

```
interface MyKebabCaseConfig {
    'foo': string;
    'foo-bar-qaz-pom-dee': string;
    'nested-object': {
        'first-name': string
        'date-of-birth': string;
        'another-one': {
            'aaa-bbb-ccc': string;
        };
        'some-array': string[];
    };
    'array-with-deep-object': SomeDeepObject[][];
}

interface SomeDeepObject {
    'aaa-bbb-ccc': string;
    'deep-array-of-strings': string[][][][];
    'deep-array-of-another-object': {
        'ddd-eee-fff': string;
    }[][][]
}

const transformed: KeysToCamelCase<MyKebabCaseConfig, '-'> = {
    foo: '',
    fooBarQazPomDee: '',
    nestedObject: {
        firstName: '',
        dateOfBirth: '',
        anotherOne: {
            aaaBbbCcc: ''
        },
        someArray: []
    },
    arrayWithDeepObject: [
        [
            {
                aaaBbbCcc: '',
                deepArrayOfStrings: [ [ [ [ '' ] ] ] ],
                deepArrayOfAnotherObject: [ [ [ { dddEeeFff: '' } ] ] ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Example 2**

```
interface BangCaseObject {
    'aaa!bbb!ccc': string;
    'eee!ddd': {
        'fff!ggg': string;
    }
}

const x: KeysToCamelCase<BangCaseObject, '!'> = {
    aaaBbbCcc: '',
    eeeDdd: {
        fffGgg: ''
    }
}
```